# why wont my macro automatically run when the cell is changed?

Tags: excel, events, cell, vba

I am trying to implement and automated change function on visual basic for applications. I have recorded a macro which takes information from one sheet and inserts a new row and pastes the information on another sheet. This macro functions properly all on its own but I have not been able to make it run automatically when the specified cell has been changed. Here is the event I have attempted to implement:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)    
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("f3")) Is Nothing Then Macro9999  
End Sub
```

"f3" is the information on the first sheet that I would like copied into a new row on another sheet. `Macro9999` is the name of the macro that I have designed to accomplish this. Here is `Macro9999`:

```
Sub Macro9999()
    Sheets("9999").Select
    Rows("4:4").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("E3:F3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("9999").Select
    Range("A4:B4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
End Sub
```

When I change cell "f3" on the first sheet nothing happens, is there something I am missing? Thanks

Comment: One question about the first codeblock, in what module is the code `Private Sub Worksheet_Change ...` ?

Comment: the Worksheet_Change event will only trigger inside the sheet it's been written in. So to make it work in the first sheet , copy the Worksheet_Change sub to the first sheet too. Or, other way : you can also do a sub Workbook_SheetChange in the ThisWorkbook section.

Comment: Also i would replace `Not Intersect(Target, Range("f3")) Is Nothing` with : `target.address = "$F$3"`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! I have attempted to write the worksheet change sub into both sheets and didn't have any luck making it function. I am interested in your other suggestion about the sub workbook sheet change. I don't really understand that I'll have to do some research on it. It sounds like I would make a change event that copies range "f3" when it is changed, followed by the workbook sheet change event and then somehow write in an event which pastes the info on that sheet? Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

One possible cause is that `EnableEvents` is set to False.

Set it to True before running the actual macro:

```
Sub subEnableEvents()
    If Not (Application.EnableEvents) Then Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd get rid of `If Not (Application.EnableEvents) Then` since it makes no difference!